# Updating Total button with with Button click from calculations

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am making a point of sale systems and one of the important things I'm trying to make is a total button or just a total. So when the total button is pressed, or every time an item is added, the total will be recalculated and outputted.

I started off with just declaring the variables:

```
item1_qty = 0
item2_qty = 0
item3_qty = 0
item4_qty = 0
item5_qty = 0
item6_qty= 0
item7_qty = 0
item8_qty = 0

item1_price = 0
item2_price = 0
item3_price = 0
item4_price = 0
item5_price = 0
item6_price = 0
item7_price = 0
item8_price = 0

itemTotal=0
```

and I'm using this code for the actual item buttons (I have 4 currently just so I don't get confused but I've included the first 2)

```
#Item1 Button + Function
def item1_Button():
    global item1_qty
    item1_text = ("Chips")
    item1_price = "2.00"
    item1_qty += 1
    item1_text = (item1_text + "    "+item1_price +"    "+ str(item1_qty)) #concatonates text & variable
    item1.config(text=item1_text) #updates label text - doesn't add multiple 
    item1.place(x=0, y=0) #places label within the frame
    
item1_Button = Button(itemFrame, text="Chips", width=10, height=10, command=item1_Button)
#creates button + links to function
item1_Button.grid(row=1, column=1) #positions button
item1 = Label(receiptFrame)#creates label for button

#Item2 Button + Function
def item2_Button():
    global item2_qty
    item2_text = "Fish & Chips"
    item2_price = "5.00"
    item2_qty += 1
    item2_text = (item2_text + "    "+item2_price +"    "+ str(item2_qty)) #concatonates text & variable
    item2.config(text=item2_text) #updates label text - doesn't add multiple 
    item2.place(x=0, y=50)
    
item2_Button = Button(itemFrame, text="Fish & Chips", width=10, height=10, command=item2_Button)
item2_Button.grid(row=1, column=2)
item2 = Label(receiptFrame)
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing in terms of the actual total button, so I have kind of just started off with this:

```
def updateTotal():
    global item1_price, item2_price, item3_price, item4_price
    global item1_qty, item2_qty, item3_qty, item4_qty
    itemPrice = item1_price + item2_price + item3_price + item4_price
    itemQuantity = item1_qty + item2_qty + item3_qty + item4_qty
    itemTotal = (itemPrice * itemQuantity)
    totalPrice.config(text=str(itemTotal))
    
totalPrice = Label(totalFrame, font=("arial", 25), text="0"+str(itemTotal))
totalPrice.place(x=10, y=10)

totalButton = Button(totalFrame, text="Total", command=updateTotal, width=15, height=5)
totalButton.place(x=450, y=0)
```

Is there something I need to do different in terms of how I use the variables?

I would prefer if the total was just text that updated every time an Item button was clicked instead of a Total button but I would appreciate some guidance as nothing is happening at the moment and I'm not entirely sure what I need to do as I'm fairly new with tkinter.

Comment: Provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and increase your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 0):

You didnt provide a minimal reproducible example and this post is 2 months old so im not gonna really explain the code and it is mostly self explanatory.

used f-strings, they are like this:

```
intensifier = input("Enter an intensifier: ")
adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")

sentence = f"This is {intensifier} {adjective}"

print(sentence)
```

The curly-brackets let you enter none string values and are automatically turned into a string. (Useable in most scenarios and no concatenation)

Changed items into lists, lists can be used like this:

```
list1 = ["value1",2,[value3]]
print(list1[0]) #Would print, "value1"
print(list1[1:2])#Would print, [2,[value3]]
```

Listbox is a box of lists, you can add stuff into it using

```
listbox.insert(<place to add to>, <object to add>)
```

Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Receipt System")

items_qty = [0,0,0,0]
items_price = [2,5,0,0]
items_text = ["Chips","Fish&chips","",""]
global itemTotal #Global variable
items_total = [0,0,0,0]

currency = "£" #Sets currency

#Functions
def addItem(x):
    items_qty[x] += 1 #Adds 1
    totalPrice = items_qty[x] * items_price[x] #quantity * price
    text = f"{items_qty[x]}x {items_text[x]} {currency}{totalPrice}" 
    for i in range(0, receipt.size()):        
        if items_text[x] in receipt.get(i):
            receipt.delete(i)
    receipt.insert(END, text)
    updateTotal(x) 

def updateTotal(x):
    global items_total
    items_total[x] = items_qty[x] * items_price[x] #quantity * price
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, len(items_total)):
        total += items_total[i]
    totalPrice.config(text=f"Total: {currency}{str(total)}")

#UI
itemFrame = Frame(root)
itemFrame.pack(pady = 10)
receiptFrame = Frame(root)
receiptFrame.pack(pady = 10)
    
item1Btn = Button(itemFrame, text=f"Chips - {currency}{items_price[0]}", command=lambda: addItem(0)).pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)
item2Btn = Button(itemFrame, text=f"Fish & Chips - {currency}{items_price[1]}", command=lambda: addItem(1)).pack(side = LEFT, padx =10)

receipt = Listbox(receiptFrame, selectmode = SINGLE, width = 30) #Receipt list
receipt.pack()

totalPrice = Label(receiptFrame, text = f"Total: {currency}0")
totalPrice.pack(pady = 10)
root.mainloop()
```